# Ensure value range for python list

Tags: python, list

I want a function that takes a list and returns that list with any elements less than 0 or greater than "upper" removed.

I figured out how to do it with a list comprehension, but I can't figure out why this didn't work:

```
dim = 4

def ensure_values(l, upper=dim**2):
    for i in l:
        if i < 0 or i >= upper:
            l.remove(i)
    return l

l = [0,2,-3,5]

ensure_values(l)
[0,2,-3,5]
```

I expected [0,2,5].

Comment: The list is changing while you are modifying it, causing the iteration to skip values.  List comprehension is better in this case, but if you want, you can build up a list of values to remove, then remove those values later.

Comment: It does work. Start a new session, copy paste your code, it works. Plus what @swstephe said: use a copy `l2=l[:]` for instance, and remove from l2, and return l2.

Comment: It works as long as you only have one out-of-range value in the list.

Comment: fredtantini - you are right.

In ipython, however, it does in fact output [0,2,-3,5], which is bizarre.

Comment: swstephe - that's sort of what I figured must be going on, but the syntax is very suggestive: it reads as iteration over items, not over indices.  So I figured, removing an item that has already been through the iteration shouldn't affect the rest, but I guess that's not how it works.

Comment: Modifying an item while looping over the item plunges you into implementation-specific details.  You really can't be sure what will happen.  It's simplest and best simply to create a new list that contains just what you want it to contain.

Answer (score 3):

Best practice in Python would be for your function to return a new list that contains only the desired elements.  This is best done with a list comprehension.

```
dim = 4

def ensure_values(lst, upper=dim**2):
    return [n for n in lst if 0 < n <= upper]

lst = [0,2,-3,5]

assert ensure_values(lst) == [2, 5]
```

Note that I was able to use the expression `0 < n <= upper`.  That's not legal in C or most other languages, but in Python it is legal and does what one would expect it to do.

Also, I recommend against using `l` as a variable name.  It looks almost exactly like a `1` or an `I` in many fonts.  Recommended practice is to use `lst` or `L` for a short name for a list.

The use of `l` as a variable name is specifically dis-recommended in the PEP 8 coding style guidelines for Python.  Here's a link:

http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id29

Answer (score 1):

You could hange your loop so it iterates over a copy of the list, which avoids modifying the list you're iterating over, because that won't work in many cases.

```
dim = 4

def ensure_values(l, upper=dim**2):
    for i in l[:]:  # iterate over copy of list
        if i < 0 or i >= upper:
            l.remove(i)
    return l

l = [0, 2, -3, 20, 5]

print ensure_values(l)  # -> [0, 2, 5]
```

A more "Pythonic" way to do it — because it's shorter and doesn't need a copy of the list — would be to use a list comprehension. Note the condition had to be reversed because it's now being used to determine when to *keep* elements.

```
l = [i for i in l if i >= 0 and i < dim**2]

print l  # -> [0, 2, 5]
```

Comment: This will work but it's not best practice.  It would be better to make a new list with only the desired elements, rather than mutating the original list in place.  And in Python it is preferred to return `None` from any function that mutates an argument, because of "Command-Query Separation".  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777122/why-does-sort-cause-the-list-to-be-none-in-python

Comment: @steveha: While I agree, that's not what the OP asked for. IMHO, the best way is to not use a function at all and instead use a list-comp as shown in my updated answer.

Comment: @steveha: P.S. One argument against returning `None` instead of the mutated argument is that it will mean the result can't be chained with another operation -- so there may be other considerations.

Comment: I am well aware that returning `None` means you can't chain with the result.  That is one of the reasons why best practice is to return a new list containing only the desired stuff.  In Python, all the built-in stuff obeys Command-Query Separation and it is very strongly disrecommended to break this.

Comment: @steveha: Oh goodness, let us hope no one ever fails to follow a **recommendation**...

Comment: It is better to follow a recommendation than not, *unless* there is a compelling benefit to be gained.  What compelling benefit is there to writing this function to work differently than every built-in function in Python that mutates an object?  I know that when I get an object back from a function, I expect that the function didn't mutate its argument... what benefit do you derive from breaking my expectation?  I am not the boss of you, so you may do as you wish and it doesn't matter to me, but when I'm giving advice here I try to give Pythonic answers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a filter?

```
def ensure_values(l, upper=dim**2):
   return filter(lambda x: x>0 or x<upper, l)
```