# How to sort a list using .sort method(not sorted)?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

I am not sure what is wrong with my code I have tried but failed. I know that the sorted function does sort the list but I don't want to use the sorted function. Instead I just want to use sort. Here is my code:

```
def assignment():
    fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
    if len(fname) == 0:
        fname = "romeo.txt"
    fh = open(fname)
    lst = list()
    for line in fh:
        x = line.rstrip()
        lst.append(x.split(" "))
        for elem in lst:
            print elem.sort()


assignment()
```

result:

```
none
```

However I when I try this code things kind of work but aren't working as I wanted

```
def assignment():
    fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")

    if len(fname) == 0:
        fname = 'romeo.txt'

    fh = open(fname)
    lst = list()

    for line in fh:
        x = line.rstrip()
        lst.append(x.split(" "))
        for elem in lst:
            print elem.sort()
    print lst
assignment()
```

result:

```
Enter file name: 
None
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: sort the list, not each element in the list.

Comment: `elem.sort()` sorts `elem` *in place* and returns None.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777122/why-does-sort-cause-the-list-to-be-none-in-python for a similar issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do these list operations (methods) return None, rather than the resulting list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-do-these-list-operations-methods-return-none-rather-than-the-resulting-li)

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort string elements using sort().however you can do like this

```
  for elem in lst:
      print ''.join(sorted(elem))
```

input :asdaa
output:aaads

Answer (score 0):

`.sort` method sort the list and returns nothing (`None`), if you want to print the list, then print the list.

This should produce the expected output:

```
...
for elem in lst:
    elem.sort()
    print elem
...
```