# why is len([1]) giving me a "NoneType" error

Tags: python, python-2.7, nonetype

I am currently learning how to code python 2.7 but I have run into a confusing error in the following code which attempts (very inefficiently I assume) to return the median of an input.

```
def median(lst):

    lst = lst.sort()
    median = 0

    if len(lst) == 1:
        median = lst[0]            
    elif len(lst) % 2 == 0:
        median_sum = lst[len(lst) / 2 - 1] + lst[len(lst) / 2 + 1]
        median = median_sum / 2.0
    else:
        median = lst[len(lst)/ 2 - 1]

    return median

print median([1])
```

above is my code and it keeps giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/SAVED DOCS/test3.py", line 16, in <module>
    print median([1])
  File "C:/Python27/SAVED DOCS/test3.py", line 6, in median
    if len(lst) == 1:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

it seems as though it is having an issue with me calling len(lst) where lst = [1] because python seems to think it is a None variable? I'm quite confused.

On the console terminal for python I can type len([1]) and I get a result of 1 without any issue. Also keep in mind I am fully aware this is not the best way to do what I am trying to do but I am just starting to learn python!

Any ideas?

Comment: It didn't occur to you to actually check the value of `lst`?!?

Comment: what do you mean? I was assuming the input would always be a list of integers if thats what youre referring to?

Comment: You change `lst` at the start of the function; you didn't check to see what it got changed to?

Comment: The most important step in understanding error messages is to **read them**. Notice how it says: "TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()". So, there is something on the line of code in question which is an `object of type 'NoneType'`. A bit of searching will easily tell you that there is only one such value: `None`. Is `[1]` the same thing as `None`? Clearly not. The error message also shows us the code: `if len(lst) == 1:`. What thing is being passed to `len`? It is `lst`. Therefore, `lst` must be the `None`. Therefore, **it must not be `[1]` as expected**. Check your assumptions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`lst.sort()` sorts the list in-place and returns `None`. So `lst = lst.sort()` sets `lst` to `None`.

I think the best fix is to do

```
lst = sorted(lst)
```

This doesn't change the list in-place, so that variables referring to the same list outside of this function are unchanged.

Comment: out of curiosity: is there a reason you prefer `lst = sorted(lst)` to `lst.sort()`? (i don't disagree here! +1'd anyway!)

Comment: The `.sort()` was designed to return `None` to remind the programmer that it sorts in-place. Isn't it ironic?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: yes, if you use lst.sort(), then any variable outside of the function referring to this list is also sorted, a function shouldn't mutate its arguments unexpectedly.

Comment: oh, good point. but if `lst` were local only (and not a function argument or something with potentially other side-effects) then there is no difference, right?

Comment: Right, then I think sorting in place is the more logical thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your title is mistaken. [list.sort()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) returns None because it operates by side effect; the first line discarded the list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `lst.sort()` which returns `None`, you can use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) built-in function like below:

```
lst = sorted(lst)
```

Now, `lst` contains your sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

think your problem is that lst.sort() returns None.

"TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"

see how to solve it here.
[Why does '.sort()' cause the list to be 'None' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777122/why-does-sort-cause-the-list-to-be-none-in-python#9777176)