# python matrix iteration issue - updates matrix on iteration - reference?

Tags: python

I am not an expert on python but why does below code change matrix?

```
matrix=[[1,2,3],[3,1,2],[2,3,1]]
for x in matrix:
    x.sort()

print (matrix)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: You used sort to re-arrange numbers in order.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777122/why-does-sort-cause-the-list-to-be-none-in-python

Comment: I can't understand the question. **What do you think should happen instead**? Why?

Answer (score 2):

The variable `matrix` is a list of lists. The method [`sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort), when applied to one of the items in `matrix`, sorts the list (that is, the item in `matrix` that is a list) in place.

If this is not the desired behavior and what is needed instead is a sorted copy of that list, you could do this using [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```py
for x in matrix:
    y = sorted(x)
```

Alternatively, you could first copy the list item and then call the `sort()` method on the copy:

```py
for x in matrix:
    y = x[:]
    y.sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

[`sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) sorts the list inplace in python.
If you don't want to sort it inplace you can use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).

```
>>> dummy_list = [3,2,5]
>>> dummy_list.sort()
>>> dummy_list
[2, 3, 5]
>>> dummy_list1 = [3,2,5]
>>> sorted(dummy_list)
[2, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

`.sort` changes the `list` without assignment (in place)

```py
matrix = [[1,2,3],[3,1,2],[2,3,1]]
for x in matrix:
    # This sorts the list, and replaces it in matrix with the sorted version
    x.sort()

print (matrix)
```

It works without an assignment (`=`), as `.sort` knows the memory position of the `list` in the array.